# A good wallet for Taproot multisig?

Tags: multi-signature, taproot

Sparrow only has Taproot single sig, and it is based on Xpub, which is a hodgepodge duct tape method combining pre-taproot and taproot.

Electrum zero Taproot. When asked "wen Taproot" response is "it will be ready when it is ready".

Muun has multisig taproot but the company holds a key.

Any good wallets that support Taproot multisig for cold storage?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/115700/how-do-i-create-a-taproot-multisig-address-requiring-21-of-210-keys-to-spend

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [Nunchuk](https://nunchuk.io/), it is a multisig wallet supporting taproot, air-gapped signing and you don't necessarily need to have a third party key (it's a paid option).